# GConf-WARNING **: Got Disconnected from DBus

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I see this error in `~/.xsession-errors` and it appears that gnome-settings-daemon ends up 'not responding' because of this.

Please note that I have been running this OS on this machine for nearly four years with very few issues and none recently.

**Background:**
I was using this computer and this login for work yesterday and shut down normally at the end of the day. Today, I started my computer and it hung after login, but before the desktop fully rendered (my custom background didn't even appear). I held down the power button to reboot and on login things looked 'off'. For instance, I keep the volume muted and the indicator showed it was turned all the way down instead of muted. I'm running Ubuntu on a mac and when I hit Fn+F10/11/12, nothing happened, but this usually works fine to change the volume. I tried rebooting again, to no avail. I was low on disk space, so I deleted some files and that didn't help, either.

I have a secondary login that is nearly identical to the first. Upon logging in under that user, everything works normally, so it does not appear to be a systemic problem.

**Thoughts So Far**
I have done a bunch of googling for the errors in `.xsession-errors` to no avail. (Many of them were 'fixed' by doing a full re-install of the OS). I can't believe that this is more complicated than deleting a pid file or changing permissions on a file/folder somewhere.

Here is the full `.xsession-errors`:

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: 24: /home/user/.profile: [[: not found

(gnome-settings-daemon:2684): power-plugin-WARNING **: gnome-session is not available

(gnome-settings-daemon:2684): color-plugin-WARNING **: failed to get edid: unable to get EDID for output
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
Initializing composite options...done
** Message: applet now removed from the notification area
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing snap options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing resize options...done
** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
Initializing place options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing grid options...done
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/home/user/.compiz/session/102a606085d2f2b121146238696957190200000026300034"
Initializing session options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing scale options...done
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done

(compiz:2702): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed
Initializing unityshell options...done
Setting Update "main_menu_key"
Setting Update "run_key"
Setting Update "run_command_screenshot_key"
Setting Update "run_command_window_screenshot_key"
Setting Update "zoom_in_button"
Setting Update "zoom_out_button"
Setting Update "icon_size"
** Message: moving back from GtkStatusIcon to indicator

** (zeitgeist-datahub:2970): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:227: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!
gnome-session[2630]: WARNING: Client '/org/gnome/SessionManager/Client2' failed to reply before timeout

** (update-notifier:3170): WARNING **: log file empty (logrotate?) /var/log/dpkg.log


** (update-notifier:3170): WARNING **: log file empty (logrotate?) /var/log/apt/term.log


(nm-applet:2711): GConf-WARNING **: Got Disconnected from DBus.

** Message: PID 2711 (we are 2711) sent signal 15, shutting down...

(nm-applet:2711): GConf-WARNING **: The connection to DBus was broken. Can't reinitialize it.

(nm-applet:2711): libappindicator-WARNING **: Unable to send signal for NewStatus: The connection is closed
Terminated
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 357 requests (357 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

Most of this matches the `.xsession-errors` from the login that 'works'. This is the part that differs:

```
(nm-applet:2711): GConf-WARNING **: Got Disconnected from DBus.

** Message: PID 2711 (we are 2711) sent signal 15, shutting down...

(nm-applet:2711): GConf-WARNING **: The connection to DBus was broken. Can't reinitialize it.

(nm-applet:2711): libappindicator-WARNING **: Unable to send signal for NewStatus: The connection is closed
Terminated
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 357 requests (357 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

And I believe that the last couple messages are due to 'forcing' gnome-settings-daemon to stop when I log out. On logout, a dialog comes up asking if I want to force quit gnome-settings-daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do an update of something that broke it? Have you tried purging and reinstalling xorg? I would try reinstalling xorg.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-tiphow-to-removeinstall-and-reconfigure-xorg-without-reinstalling-ubuntu.html

Comment: I have not, as everything works fine on another login. This is my only 'working' computer at the moment and I'm hesitant to do something that may cause problems system-wide until I get a new one, which is coming in just over a week. Until then, I'm looking for options that would only affect that user/login.

Comment: Does the non-working user happen to be an LDAP user?